# Use git command to get the hash of the commit that changed a file

Tags: git

Say in my Git repo, there is a file named `myservice.java` , what is the git command to retrieve the hash of the last commit that has created/changed that file ?

Comment: A commit has a hash; a blob has a hash... What do you mean by "commit hash of a file"?

Comment: @Jubobs, I don't know what does "blob" hash mean, is it related with Git ? I tagged my question with Git, so I suppose my question is about Git commit hash.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects for what a definition of blob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%H' -1 myservice.java
```

`--pretty=format:'%H'` means "display hash only" (you can use `%h` for displaying the short hash instead)

`-1` is for displaying only the first commit, because git log shows you the whole file history.

If you want more information about the commit, you can use:

```
git log -1 myservice.java
```

Comment: Edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log myservice.java` to get hashes of modifications for your file `myservice.java`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a command which only shows the current/latest commit hash.